# ngModel Two way binding not working in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, ngmodel

```
<input matInput placeholder="username" [(ngModel)]="userId">
<input matInput placeholder="name" [(ngModel)]="name">
```

I have also imported the FormsModule

```
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms'

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    UserInputComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    FormsModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    HttpClientModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-user-input',
  templateUrl: './user-input.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./user-input.component.css']
})

export class UserInputComponent implements OnInit {

 userId: string = 'userId';
 name: string = 'name';
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  
  }
}
```

The initial values are getting printed in the console but when a new value is entered, the variables userId and name don't get updated. if I don't give an initial value to userId and name then printing them on the console gives me undefined even after entering them from the input.
Kindly help me figure out what's the issue.

**EDIT**
The problem was fixed by including a name attribute in the input tag.

Comment: Please share a minimal working StackBlitz to understand your implementation and reply on it.

Comment: where is your console.log() ? How do you use it to print what you want to see?

Comment: i have a click event attached to a button. I'm printing the values to the console  there

Comment: on which angular version you are working?

Comment: If you just use ngModel standalone, without a form somewhere, you don't have to specify a name for the input.

But when you do use it in a form, the name attribute becomes mandatory !

Answer (score 0):

Your are not posted full code. But anyhow I add button and click event. Now when you click you need to update model then it will update values. Currently you assigned first time but when click your not assign new value to inputs

```
<input matInput placeholder="username" [(ngModel)]="userId">
    <input matInput placeholder="name" [(ngModel)]="name">
    <button (click)="test(event)" value="click"/>



import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-user-input',
  templateUrl: './user-input.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./user-input.component.css']
})

export class UserInputComponent implements OnInit {

 userId: string = 'userId';
 name: string = 'name';
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

test(e){
userId=e.target.value;
name=e.target.value;
}

  
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank Wajid. As I mentioned in the edit, my problem was resolved by simply adding a name attribute. As it turns out, for input tags ngModel needs a name attribute.